# Programmatically disable Game Object vs Disable Script

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine

If I have an Empty Game Object with only a script attached is there any performance implications on programmatically disabling the Game Object vs disabling the Script Attached?

When is better to disable the GO and when is better to disable the Script?

[image]

Comment: It actually depends one your needs, i think disabling object is already better as it does not render then, in case of empties or without renderer, i dont know how much difference it will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disable your Gameobject you turn off it fully (renderer, components and scripts) and not be rendered every frame.

If you turn off script or component only, gameobject still active and rendering and can Access to all their component and scripts except inactive ítems.

You increase your perfomance if you disable your gameobject if not need to render it.